# docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /var/lib/postgresql/data

Tags: postgresql, windows, docker

I'm trying to install the postgres docker container on windows.

When running the code below I get an error that I'm unable to overcome:

```
docker run -it \
  -e POSTGRES_USER="root" \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" \
  -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi" \
  -v c:\Users\arunn\Code\data_eng\ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  postgres:13
```

This is the error I get and I suppose the issue is with my volume path:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /var/lib/postgresql/data.
```

I encountered this error while working through the first week of the Data Engineering Zoomcamp: https://github.com/DataTalksClub/data-engineering-zoomcamp/tree/main/week_1_basics_n_setup